# memset() and memcpy() using D slices

Tags: d, memcpy, memset, compiled-language, ctfe

In the D language, what are the equivalents to the following statements
assuming the code :-

```
int size = 8;
int shift = 1; 
int[size] skip;
int[size]  suff;

memcpy(&skip[0], &skip[0]+shift, (m-shift)*(int.sizeof));
memset(&skip[0]+(m-shift),0, shift*(int.sizeof))
```

I was thinking conversion would be :-

```
skip[0 .. size-1] = skip[shift .. size-1   ];  //For the memcpy();
skip[0 .. size-1] = 0;                         //For the  memset();
```

But this doesn't seem to work for me as dmd(v2.066.1) gives the error `slice [8..7] exceeds array bounds [0..8]` .

Comment: [0..8] means [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]. So, you need `size` where you write `size-1`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `m` represents length of the array in your `memcpy`/`memset` code.

```
skip[0 .. size - shift] = skip[shift .. size]; // may throw
skip[size - shift .. size] = 0;
```

Note that you'll get runtime error on first line if array bounds overlap.